# Newtonsoft.Json Deserialize fails

Tags: json.net

After refactoring a class, serializing it with

```cs
file.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented));
```

works as expected and produces the json file described in this issue.
However, deserializing no longer works.

http://json2csharp.com was able to retrieve the object structure properly.

#### Source/destination types

```cs
 public class VinciModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string VidiWorkspaceDir { get; set; }
        public string ViDiWorkspaceName { get; set; }

        public int NRows { get; set; }
        public List<List<object>> Rows { get; set; }
        public int NChocolates { get; set; }
        public List<StreamInfo> StreamList { get; set; }
        public float BlisterWidth { get; set; }
        public float BlisterHeight { get; set; }
    }

    public class Socket
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public string StreamName { get; set; }
        public Rectangle ROI { get; set; }
    }

    public class StreamInfo
    {
        public string StreamName { get; set; }
        public List<Socket> Sockets { get; set; } = new List<Socket>();
    }
}
```

#### Source/destination JSON

```
{
  "Name": "sdgsd",
  "VidiWorkspaceDir": "D:\\VidiProjects\\VidiWorkspace-demo",
  "ViDiWorkspaceName": "box2shrink_2",
  "NRows": 1,
  "Rows": [
    [
      {
        "Index": 0,
        "StreamName": "mystream",
        "ROI": "0, 0, 5, 51"
      },
      {
        "Index": 0,
        "StreamName": "1",
        "ROI": "5, 0, 5, 51"
      },
      {
        "Index": 0,
        "StreamName": "2",
        "ROI": "11, 0, 5, 51"
      },
      {
        "Index": 0,
        "StreamName": "mystream",
        "ROI": "17, 0, 5, 51"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "NChocolates": 4,
  "StreamList": [
    {
      "StreamName": "mystream",
      "Sockets": [
        {
          "Index": 0,
          "StreamName": "mystream",
          "ROI": "0, 0, 5, 51"
        },
        {
          "Index": 0,
          "StreamName": "mystream",
          "ROI": "17, 0, 5, 51"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "StreamName": "1",
      "Sockets": [
        {
          "Index": 0,
          "StreamName": "1",
          "ROI": "5, 0, 5, 51"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "StreamName": "2",
      "Sockets": [
        {
          "Index": 0,
          "StreamName": "2",
          "ROI": "11, 0, 5, 51"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "BlisterWidth": 23.0,
  "BlisterHeight": 51.0
}
```

#### Error

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 
'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'Rows[0]', line 8, position 7.'

#### Steps to reproduce

```cs
using (var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path))
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VinciModel>(file.ReadToEnd());
```

Worked before the class got refactored

I also tried :

```cs
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(file.ReadToEnd());
```

and got :
'Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'Rows[0][0]'.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my class had a non default constructor and no default constructor. The error message is irrelevant.